# how to achieve best tcpip socket data-rate performance

Tags: linux, windows, sockets, tcp

Packing as much data as possible per tcp packet will obviously decrease the relative weight of overhead. Increasing buffer size increases robustness against peaks of CPU usage.

But what else can be done to achieve highest data rates?

Is increasing the priority of the data reader thread a good idea? If the highest priority was used, could this thread compete for CPU usage with the Network driver and actually harm performance?

Is blocking or non-blocking best in terms of achievable data rates?

At very high data rates, can overflow of the receive buffers be detected as the buffer gets to, say, 90% and trigger a high priority read?

Other techniques for high data-rate over tcpip sockets?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use busy polling for getting data from NIC. This can improve the data rate by reducing interrupt overhead. This is done in high performance packet processing frameworks such as DPDK.

Another way would be to avoid copying packets from kernel space to userspace. I don't whether this is possible in your case. Avoiding copying packets by mapping kernel memory to userspace memory. Copying data to userspace is one of the most time consuming step in network stacks. Again this is done in DPDK.